# Saving WMS locally as raster DTM?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, wms, dem

I am interested in a DTM made available via a WMS service. I do know how to add the DTM as layer in ArcGIS (10.1 advanced lisence), but I do not know if it is possible to save the DTM (or part thereof) locally as a raster dataset.

Is there any procedure to get that accomplished?

Comment: Most WMS services do not serve the actual DTM but a tiled image of it rendered on a scale of 0-256 which, depending on zoom level, will be down-sampled.  In other words, Unless the WMS is specifically set up to do so, you will not get anything like the original data and you are better advised to source the original data.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the comment by @MappaGnosis:

> Most WMS services do not serve the actual DTM but a tiled image of it
>   rendered on a scale of 0-256 which, depending on zoom level, will be
>   down-sampled. In other words, Unless the WMS is specifically set up to
>   do so, you will not get anything like the original data and you are
>   better advised to source the original data.

To achieve your goal I think you would need to be working with a [Web Coverage Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Coverage_Service) (WCS) instead.